# Best way to draw scaled polygons in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-collection

I want to draw pictures like this

[image: Originally from wikipedia]

or this one

[image: Originally from wikipedia].

It is clear how to do this "manually" with TikZ. However is there a way to do it automatically. I.e. I just want to define the polygon (for example the yellow triangles in the pictures above), a center point Z and a scaling factor m and then get the corresponding picture (as in my examples) automatically generated by that input data.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I assume it is because you didn't show what you've tried so far. This might be seen as a `draw-this-for-me` question.

Answer (score 21):

Here is a general solution... but not completely since it can not manage the content of nodes (*see below for a simpler solution but less general*).

I create a new `homothety` option usable with a path. This options can store the result of an homothetic transformation applied to this path. Some subkeys control the parameters:

- `scale` is used to specify the scale (default value: 1).
- `center` is used to specify the center (default value: {0,0}).
- `store in` is used to specify the macro that stores the transformed path.
- `name` is a prefix to name each vertex of the transformed path (default value: `homothety`).

**A little example to show the syntax**

```
\draw[homothety={scale=2,center={1,1},name=A,store in=\transpath}] (0,0) -- (3,4);
```

As usual, the path is drawn. But in addition:

- A new path (the original path transformed by the homothety whose scale is 2 and center is (1,1)) is stored in `\transpath` macro.
- The vertices of this new path are `A-1`, `A-2`, etc.
- The `homothetypoints` counter gives the number of vertices.

Then, to draw the transformed path with labels, you can use:

```
\draw \transpath;
\foreach \num in {1,...,\arabic{homothetypoints}}{
   \node[below] (A-\num) {$A_\num$};
 }
```

**Strengths and limitations**

- You can use `homothety` just to copy a path (with scale=1 and center={0,0}).
- The original path can use nodes, coordinates, holes in its definition.
- Each vertex of the transformed path is stored.
- But, the content of a node is not transformed...

**A larger example** *(result)*

[image]

**A larger example** *(long commented code)*

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing}

\makeatletter
% to produce automaticaly homothetic paths
\newcounter{homothetypoints} % number of vertices of path
\tikzset{
  % homothety is a family...
  homothety/.style={homothety/.cd,#1},
  % ...with some keys
  homothety={
    % parameters
    scale/.store in=\homothety@scale,% scale of current homothetic transformation
    center/.store in=\homothety@center,% center of current homothetic transformation
    name/.store in=\homothety@name,% prefix for named vertices
    % default values
    scale=1,
    center={0,0},
    name=homothety,
    % initialization
    init memoize homothetic path/.code={
      \xdef#1{}
      \setcounter{homothetypoints}{0}
    },
    % incrementation
    ++/.code={\addtocounter{homothetypoints}{1}},
    % a style to store an homothetic transformation of current path into #1 macro
    store in/.style={
      init memoize homothetic path=#1,
      /tikz/postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
          show path construction,
          moveto code={
            % apply homothetic transformation to this segment and add result to #1
            \xdef#1{#1 ($(\homothety@center)!\homothety@scale!(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)$)}
            % name this vertex
            \coordinate[homothety/++](\homothety@name-\arabic{homothetypoints})
            at ($(\homothety@center)!\homothety@scale!(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)$);
          },
          lineto code={
            % apply homothetic transformation to this segment and add result to #1
            \xdef#1{#1 -- ($(\homothety@center)!\homothety@scale!(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$)}
            % name this vertex
            \coordinate[homothety/++] (\homothety@name-\arabic{homothetypoints})
            at ($(\homothety@center)!\homothety@scale!(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$);
          },
          curveto code={
            % apply homothetic transformation to this segment and add result to #1
            \xdef#1{#1
              .. controls ($(\homothety@center)!\homothety@scale!(\tikzinputsegmentsupporta)$)
              and ($(\homothety@center)!\homothety@scale!(\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)$)
              .. ($(\homothety@center)!\homothety@scale!(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$)}
            % name this vertex
            \coordinate[homothety/++] (\homothety@name-\arabic{homothetypoints})
            at ($(\homothety@center)!\homothety@scale!(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$);
          },
          closepath code={
            % apply homothetic transformation to this segment and add result to #1
            \xdef#1{#1 -- cycle ($(\homothety@center)!\homothety@scale!(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$)}
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\bfseries\sffamily]

  % some styles
  \tikzset{
    dashed line/.style={draw=#1!50!gray,dashed,line width=.4pt},
    filled shape/.style={draw=black,line width=1pt,fill=#1,fill opacity=.4},
    dot/.style={draw,line width=.4pt,fill=#1!50!gray},
  }

  % draw a path (and memomize its definition into \mypath with points named A-1, A-2,...)
  \draw[filled shape=cyan,homothety={store in=\mypath,name=A}]
  (0,0) to[bend right] ++(2,2) -- ++(-1,1) to[bend left] ++(-2,-2) -- cycle;

  % add a label to each vertex
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\nbpoints}{\arabic{homothetypoints}}
  \foreach \num in {1,...,\nbpoints} {
    \node[above] at (A-\num) {$A_\num$};
  }
  % first center: c1
  \fill[dot=green] (0,3) coordinate (c1) circle(2pt) node[right]{$c_1$};
  % store two homothetic transformations of \mypath
  \path[homothety={store in=\secondpath,scale=-1,center=c1}] \mypath;
  \path[homothety={store in=\thirdpath,scale=-2,center=c1,name=B}] \mypath;
  % draw them
  \draw[filled shape=green] \secondpath;
  \draw[filled shape=green] \thirdpath;
  % for each vertex of \thirdpath, add a label and draw a dashed line to
  % corresponding vertex of \mypath
  \foreach \num in {1,...,\nbpoints} {
    \node[below] at (B-\num) {$B_\num$};
    \draw[dashed line=green] (B-\num) -- (A-\num);
  }

  % second center: c2
  \fill[dot=red] (-4,-1) coordinate (c2) circle(2pt) node[above]{$c_2$};
  % store two homothetic transformations of \mypath
  \path[homothety={store in=\secondpath,scale=2,center=c2,name=C}] \mypath;
  \path[homothety={store in=\thirdpath,scale=.5,center=c2}] \mypath;
  % draw them
  \draw[filled shape=red] \secondpath;
  \draw[filled shape=red] \thirdpath;
  % for each vertex of \thirdpath, draw a dashed line to center and add a label
  \foreach \num in {1,...,\nbpoints} {
    \node[above] at (C-\num) {$C_\num$};
    \draw[dashed line=red] (C-\num) -- (c2);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Simple solution but with limitations**

You can use `calc` library and scopes with `scale` and `shift` options to draw homothetic transformations. It is simple but ***your path must be defined only by numeric coordinates***.

Result:

[image: simple solution]

Code (commented):

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % some styles
  \tikzset{
    filled shape/.style={draw=black,line width=1pt,fill=#1,fill opacity=.4},
    dot/.style={draw,line width=.4pt,fill=#1!50!gray},
    homothety at/.style args={#1 scaled by #2}{shift={($(#1)!#2!(0,0)$)},scale=#2},
  }
  % path definition (numeric coordinates only!)
  \def\mypath{(0,0) to[bend right] ++(2,2) -- ++(-1,1) to[bend left] ++(-2,-2) -- cycle}
  % draw this path
  \draw[filled shape=cyan] \mypath;
  % center of homothetic transformation
  \fill[dot=green] (-1,2) coordinate (c1) circle(2pt) node[above]{$c_1$};
  % first transformation (scale=-1, center=c1)
  \begin{scope}[homothety at=c1 scaled by -1]
    \draw[filled shape=red] \mypath;
  \end{scope}
  % second transformation (scale=2, center=c1)
  \begin{scope}[homothety at=c1 scaled by 2]
    \draw[filled shape=red] \mypath;
    \draw[dashed] (c1) -- (0,0);
    \draw[dashed] (c1) -- (2,2);
    \draw[dashed] (c1) -- (1,3);
    \draw[dashed] (c1) -- (-1,1);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

run with `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pspolygon[linecolor=red!60,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!40!white](-2,-3)(-1,-1)(1,-1)%
\psHomothetie(0,0){-1.5}{\pspolygon[linecolor=blue!60,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!40!white](-2,-3)(-1,-1)(1,-1)}
\psHomothetie(0,0){1.5}{\pspolygon[linecolor=green!60,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!40!white,opacity=0.5](-2,-3)(-1,-1)(1,-1)}
\psset{linestyle=dashed,linewidth=0.5pt}
\psRelLine(0,0)(-2,-3){-1.75}{A'}\psRelLine(0,0)(-2,-3){1.7}{A}
\psRelLine(0,0)(-1,-1){-1.75}{B'}\psRelLine(0,0)(-1,-1){1.7}{B}
\psRelLine(0,0)(1,-1){-1.75}{C'}\psRelLine(0,0)(1,-1){1.7}{C}

\qdisk(0,0){2pt}
\end{pspicture}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

you can use *any* object for this, not only polygons. Here an example for an image:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I now managed to do the following. Any suggestions for improvements?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\newcommand {\defPoly}[3]
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{#2};%
  \coordinate (Z) at #3;%
  \draw (Z) circle (1pt);%
  \path \foreach \coord [count=\ni] in {#1} {\coord coordinate (a\ni)};
  \foreach \k [count=\ni] in {#1} {%
    \global\let\nb\ni};

  \draw (a1) \foreach \i in {2,...,\nb} {--(a\i)} --cycle; %
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\nb} {\coordinate (b\i) at ($(Z) + \m*(a\i)-\m*(Z)$);}%

  \draw (b1) \foreach \i in {2,...,\nb} {--(b\i)} -- cycle;%
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\nb}{\draw[dashed] (Z) -- (b\i);\draw[dashed] (Z) -- (a\i);}%

}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
   \defPoly{(0,0),(2,2),(1,3),(-2,4)}{3}{(-2,2)};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks! It's also nice that it works without PSTricks (which is a pain to use in pdflatex).

Answer (score 6):

Just another solution with PSTricks.

### Still Version:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-4,-3)(8,6)
% Setup the original polygon points
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={135,135,135,-45}]
    (2,2){O}
    (4,5){A}
    (6,5){B}
    (7,3){C}
% Setup the image points
\pstHomO[HomCoef=-1.1,PosAngle={315,315,135}]{O}{A,B,C}
% Draw auxiliary lines
\psset{nodesepA=-6,nodesepB=-1,linestyle=dashed,linecolor=gray}
\pstLineAB{O}{A}
\pstLineAB{O}{B}
\pstLineAB{O}{C}
% Draw the polygons
\psset{linestyle=solid,linejoin=2,linecolor=black,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.25}
\pspolygon[fillcolor=red](A)(B)(C)
\pspolygon[fillcolor=blue](A')(B')(C')
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### Animated Version:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,multido,fp}

\begin{document}

\multido{\n=0.7+-0.3}{7}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-4,-3)(8,6)
% Setup the original polygon points
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={135,135,135,-45}]
    (2,2){O}
    (4,5){A}
    (6,5){B}
    (7,3){C}
% Setup the image points
\FPifgt\n0
\pstHomO[HomCoef=\n,PosAngle={135,135,-45}]{O}{A,B,C}
\else
\pstHomO[HomCoef=\n,PosAngle={315,315,135}]{O}{A,B,C}
\fi
% Draw auxiliary lines
\psset{nodesepA=-6,nodesepB=-1,linestyle=dashed,linecolor=gray}
\pstLineAB{O}{A}
\pstLineAB{O}{B}
\pstLineAB{O}{C}
% Draw the polygons
\psset{linestyle=solid,linejoin=2,linecolor=black,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.25}
\pspolygon[fillcolor=red](A)(B)(C)
\pspolygon[fillcolor=blue](A')(B')(C')
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

### Animated version with an image:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,multido,graphicx,fp}
\psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}


\def\filename{../../../../../Images/ParisHilton}


\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{\filename}}
\psset{xunit=\dimexpr\wd\IBox/8,yunit=\dimexpr\ht\IBox/6}

\begin{document}

\multido{\n=0.80+-0.25}{8}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-14,-9)(8,6)
% Setup the original polygon points
\pstGeonode
    (-2,-1){O}
    (8,6){A}
    ([nodesep=-\wd\IBox]A){B}
    ([nodesep=-\wd\IBox,offset=-\ht\IBox]A){C}
    ([offset=-\ht\IBox]A){D}
% Setup the image points
\pstHomO[HomCoef=\n]{O}{A,B,C,D}
% Place the images
\rput[tr](A){\usebox\IBox}
\FPifgt\n0\rput[tr](A'){\scalebox{\n}{\usebox\IBox}}\fi
\FPifeq\n0\relax\fi
\FPiflt\n0\rput[tr](C'){\scalebox{\n}{\usebox\IBox}}\fi
% Draw auxiliary lines
\psset{nodesepA=-6.5,nodesepB=-.25,linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red}
\pstLineAB{O}{A}
\pstLineAB{O}{B}
\pstLineAB{O}{C}
\pstLineAB{O}{D}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hopefully the next built of PSTricks has provided us with a new feature in which the point labels are automatically placed on the angle bisector of the angle in question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the package tkz-euclide to make it very simple[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\SCALE}{3}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, 1/2/A, 4/3/B, 3/1/C}
\tkzDefPointBy[homothety=center O ratio \SCALE](A)   \tkzGetPoint{A'}
\tkzDefPointBy[homothety=center O ratio \SCALE](B)   \tkzGetPoint{B'}
\tkzDefPointBy[homothety=center O ratio \SCALE](C)   \tkzGetPoint{C'}

\tkzDrawPolygon[fill=green!30](A,B,C)
\tkzDrawPolygon(A',B',C')
\tkzDrawPoints(O)
\tkzDrawLines[dashed,blue,add= 0 and .3](O,A' O,B' O,C')
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,A',B',C')
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C,A',B',C')
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```